# Jquery Timepicker disabletimerange

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I'm using jquery timepicker and timepicker version is 1.3.x. but, in this version disable time range is not working. So i need to know the bug where i did. please find following code for your reference

```
$('#totimeofappointment').attr("placeholder", "To hh:mm").timepicker({
            timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
            interval: 15,
            minTime: '10:00',
            maxTime: '5:00pm',
            maxMinutes: 45,
            startTime: '10:00',
            dynamic: false,
            dropdown: true,
            scrollbar: true,
            disableTimeRanges: [ ['1:30pm', '2:30pm'], ['3pm', '4:01pm'] ]
            change: function (time) {
              }
});
```

**I need to restrict the time range from 1:30pm to 2:30pm**

Comment: have u found the cause and the solution? it happens exactly same to me

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing a **`comma (,)`** just after your timeRanges code:

```
$('#totimeofappointment').attr("placeholder", "To hh:mm").timepicker({
            interval: 15,
            minTime: '10:00am',
            maxTime: '5:00pm',
            maxMinutes: 45,
            startTime: '10:00am',
            dynamic: false,
            dropdown: true,
            scrollbar: true,
            disableTimeRanges: [ ['1:30pm', '2:30pm'], ['3pm', '4:01pm'] ],
            change: function (time) {
            }
});
```

Comment: dynamic value is not working like I'm trying to get some data from server via PHP or any other language. what is the solution for this?